# Logging in to IBM Cloud Container Registry fails at us.icr.io

Tags: ibm-cloud, container-registry

First of all, I am a newbie in the IBM Cloud world.

I am following some guidelines to push an image to the IBM Cloud Container Registry. But I am facing problems to login into the Container Registry.

The command that I am using is:

```
ibmcloud cr login
```

And the response is:

> Logging in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'...
>
> Logged in to 'registry.ng.bluemix.net'.
>
> Logging in to 'us.icr.io'...
>
> FAILED
>
> Failed to 'docker login' to 'us.icr.io' with error: WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
>
> Error response from daemon: Get https://us.icr.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Looking at the error `certificate signed by unknown authority` seems that my `docker` need some certificate to connect with `us.icr.io`.

My Docker version is `2.2.0.3`

Comment: Are you following this https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=container-registry-cli-plugin-containerregcli ? Are you logged in to IBM Cloud (`ibmcloud login`)?

Comment: @data_henrik I am following this https://github.com/IBM/container-service-getting-started-wt/tree/master/Lab%201 and Yes, I am logged to ibmcloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running dig against us.icr.io just to check that you are going to the right host?

This page shows all of the subnets for us.icr.io https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-firewall#firewall_outbound
They are:
169.61.234.224/29
169.61.135.160/29
169.61.46.80/29

If you aren't going to one of those, do you have some kind of proxy in place that's interfering with the DNS resolution?

Comment: You get the problem. I've just noticed that the firewall is blocking `us.icr.io` but not the IP. I look at the docs from IBM Cloud but didn't find a way to specify the IP instead of DNS.

Comment: So you should be able to set something in your hosts file to be able to set everything that goes to us.icr.io to go to a specific ip.

You can do this by editing the `/etc/hosts` file, and adding the line `us.icr.io <the ip you want to go to>`.

It's possible that you already have something in there that is causing you to go to the wrong place. Without knowing your specific set up it's difficult to suggest what is causing requests to us.icr.io to resolve to the wrong ip, but the above should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the troubleshooting documentation [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Registry?topic=registry-ts_index#ts_login).

Can you update the container-registry plugin? With the below command

```
ibmcloud plugin update container-registry
```

Also, make sure that the Docker daemon is running with the below command

```
docker ps
```

> You can't log in to IBM Cloud Container Registry.
>
> What's happening
>   The ibmcloud cr login command fails.
>
> Why it's happening
>   The following alternatives are possible causes:
>
> The container-registry CLI plug-in is out of date and needs updating.
>   Docker is not installed on your local computer, or is not running.
>   Your IBM Cloud login credentials have expired.
>   How to fix it
>
> You can fix this problem in the following ways:
>
> Upgrade to the most recent version of the container-registry CLI plug-in, see Updating the container-registry CLI plug-in.
>   Ensure that Docker is installed on your computer. If it is already installed, restart the Docker daemon.
>   Rerun the ibmcloud login command to refresh your IBM Cloud login credentials.

**Update**

There are many ways to fix the certificate issue

1. Create the client certificates following the [instructions mentioned here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#create-the-client-certificates),

> ```
> openssl genrsa -out client.key 4096
> openssl req -new -x509 -text -key client.key -out client.cert
> ```

2. Add your client certificates by following the [instructions here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#adding-client-certificates#add-client-certificates). Replace `<MyRegistry>:<Port>` with `us.icr.io`
3. For server-side certificate, check [this link](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#adding-client-certificates#add-custom-ca-certificates-server-side) for `ca.crt`

Comment: I have already updated the `ibmcloud` plugins, but I redo again to make sure and my Docker is running. It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try rerunning the ibmcloud login command? after restarting the Docker daemon?

Comment: Not sure which OS you are on. Can you try the resolution mentioned here - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8849#issuecomment-584835957

Comment: I am using OSX. I think this is the problem but I don't know how to set up this certificate.

Comment: Maybe this can help me https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/user/access-dtr/ but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Updated my answer with more information on generating certificates. If that doesn't help you can either reinstall the docker desktop for macOS or NOT RECOMMENDED - https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake by thinking I need to use the region specific endpoint. After some digging this is not the case, unless you need the specific region url for a specific reason.

As I quote from [ibm registry regions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Registry?topic=Registry-registry_overview#registry_regions) docs :

> The default instance of IBM Cloud Container Registry is the global registry. The global registry doesn't include a region in its domain name (icr.io).

Conclusion: replace `us.icr.io` with `icr.io`

---

**Update:**

Make sure you login into ibmcloud first:

```
ibmcloud login --apikey replace_me_with_IAM_apikey --no-region
```

Do second:

```
ibmcloud cr login
```